# REGEX help needed in c#

Tags: c#, regex

[image]I am very new to reg-ex and i am not sure whats going on with this one.... however my friend gave me this to solve my issue BUT somehow it is not working....

```
string: department_name:womens AND item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear

reg-ex: (department_name:([\\w-]+))?(item_type_keyword:([\\w-]+))?
```

desired output: array OR group

- 1st element should be: department_name:womens
- 2nd should be: womens
- 3rd: item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear
- 4th: base-layer-underwear

  strings can contain department_name OR item_type_keyword, BUT not mendatory, in any order

## C# Code

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(department_name:([\w-]+))?(item_type_keyword:([\w-]+))?");
Match match = regex.Match(query);
if (match.Success)
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[4].ToString()))
        d1.ItemType = match.Groups[4].ToString();
```

this C# code only returns string array with 3 element

```
1: department_name:womens
2: department_name:womens
3: womens
```

somehow it is duplicating 1st and 2nd element, i dont know why. BUT its not return the other elements that i expect..

can someone help me please...

when i am testing the regex online, it looks fine to me...

http://fiddle.re/crvw1

Thanks

Comment: becuase your regex isn't matches the inbetween ` AND `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the output you have in your question:

```
string txt = "department_name:womens AND item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear";
var reg = new Regex(@"(?:department_name|item_type_keyword):([\w-]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var ms = reg.Matches(txt);
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
foreach (Match match in ms)
{
    results.Add(match.Groups[0].Value);
    results.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}

// results is your final array containing all results
foreach (string elem in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

Prints:

```
department_name:womens
womens
item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear
base-layer-underwear
```

`match.Groups[0].Value` gives the part that matched the pattern, while `match.Groups[1].Value` will give the part captured in the pattern.

In your first expression, you have 2 capture groups; hence why you have twice `department_name:womens` appearing.

<strike>Once you get the different elements, you should be able to put them in an array/list for further processing.</strike> (Added this part in edit)

The loop then allows you to iterate over each of the matches, which you cannot exactly do with `if` and `.Match()` (which is better suited for a single match, while here I'm enabling multiple matches so the order they are matched doesn't matter, or the number of matches).

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/j3Axad)

---

```
(?:
  department_name     # Match department_name
|                     # Or
  item_type_keyword   # Match item_type_keyword
)
:
([\w-]+)              # Capture \w and - characters
```

Comment: @patel.milanb Ok, I put them all in an ArrayList for you. See the edit. I also used the `System.Collections` to be able to use an ArrayList by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use the alternation (or logical OR) operator `|` because we don't know the order of the input string.

```
(department_name:([\w-]+))|(item_type_keyword:([\w-]+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/48)

```
String input = @"department_name:womens AND item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:(department_name:([\w-]+))|(item_type_keyword:([\w-]+)))");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[4].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/BKjjNg)

Answer (score 2):

Another idea using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for capturing and getting all groups in one match:

```
^(?!$)(?=.*(department_name:([\w-]+))|)(?=.*(item_type_keyword:([\w-]+))|)
```

as a .NET String

```
"^(?!$)(?=.*(department_name:([\\w-]+))|)(?=.*(item_type_keyword:([\\w-]+))|)"
```

[test at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/p0txt) (click on .NET); [test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/mD0cR1/1)

(add `m` multiline modifier if multiline input: `"^(?m)`...)

Comment: This is comprehensive.though i didnt get what exaclty `|` is doing there

Comment: @vks the `|)` is only kind of cheat to make the match optional

Comment: Awesum that is.Nice hack to include the match in one.learnt a new one .thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use any spliting with And Or , etc that you can use

```
(department_name:(.*?)) AND (item_type_keyword:(.*?)$)
```

•1: department_name:womens
•2: womens
•3: item_type_keyword:base-layer-underwear
•4: base-layer-underwear

Comment: Maybe better `[\w-]+` instead of the lazy dot `.*?` after `item_type_keyword`

Comment: Why it fails here http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/51 ? Read the question, strings won't be in an order.

Comment: You're right @AvinashRaj well upvoted your and Jerry solution already :)

Comment: Incase special character present in department_name or item_type_keyword ([\w-]) it will not match this case

Comment: @menaka Yes, but otherwise the lazy dot might substitute to nothing ([see regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rS3hP7/1) what I mean) and OP used `[\w-]+` that seems not to be the problem imho.

Comment: please refer this(regex101.com/r/rS3hP7/2) $ is used for match at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(department_name:\w+)).*?:([\w-]+)|(?=(item_type_keyword:.*)$).*?:([\w-]+)
```

Try this.This uses a lookahead to capture then backtrack and again capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/52

Comment: Why are you using lookaheads?

Comment: @Unihedron just to be failsafe.